# SimpleXML xpath to element with certain attribute value?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have some XML like this:

```
<item>
    <custom-attributes>
      <custom-attribute attribute-id="taco">false</custom-attribute>
      <custom-attribute attribute-id="htmlContent" xml:lang="en-US">testValue</custom-attribute>
      <custom-attribute attribute-id="htmlContent" xml:lang="default">testing123</custom-attribute>
  </custom-attribute>
</item>
```

How do I use xpath to find the `custom-attribute` element than has an attribute-id of `taco`?

How do I use xpath to find the `custom-attribute` element(s) than have attribute-ids of `htmlContent`? There are 2 in this case. Also these have namespaces on them. I'm not sure if that matters or not.

I have tried something like this:

```
var_dump($xml->xpath("custom-attribute[@attribute-id='taco']"));
```

But this doesn't work. I can iterate thru the `custom-attribute` elements and look for what I need, but it would be a lot easier to simply select it via `xpath`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add double slashes to the beginning of your xpath:

```
$source = <<<X
<item>
    <custom-attributes>
      <custom-attribute attribute-id="taco">false</custom-attribute>
      <custom-attribute attribute-id="htmlContent" xml:lang="en-US">testValue</custom-attribute>
      <custom-attribute attribute-id="htmlContent" xml:lang="default">testing123</custom-attribute>
  </custom-attributes>
</item>
X;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source);

$taco             = $xml->xpath("//custom-attribute[@attribute-id='taco']")[0];
$htmlContentArray = $xml->xpath("//custom-attribute[@attribute-id='htmlContent']");

echo "taco       : ", $taco, PHP_EOL;
echo "htmlContent: ", implode(', ', $htmlContentArray), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
taco       : false
htmlContent: testValue, testing123
```

**Update**

For your question in the comments, regarding searching within an `item` node; you can use `.//` to start the search from the current node.

```
// Find an item, then do an xpath on the result of that
// to find the custom attribute element.
// <items> tag added as <item> would otherwise be the root element,
// which would make the example quite pointless.
$source = <<<X
<items>
    <item>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="taco">false</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="htmlContent" xml:lang="en-US">testValue</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="htmlContent" xml:lang="default">testing123</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </item>
    <item>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="taco">true</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="htmlContent" xml:lang="en-US">item 2 testValue</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="htmlContent" xml:lang="default">item 2 testing456</custom-attribute>
          </custom-attributes>
    </item>
</items>
X;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source);

$item             = $xml->item[1]; // Get second item
$taco             = $item->xpath(".//custom-attribute[@attribute-id='taco']");
$htmlContentArray = $item->xpath(".//custom-attribute[@attribute-id='htmlContent']");

echo "taco from second item: ", $taco[0], PHP_EOL;
echo "html from second item: ", implode(', ', $htmlContentArray), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
taco from second item: true
html from second item: item 2 testValue, item 2 testing456
```

Comment: So xpath returns an array, not a SimpleXMLElement?

Comment: Actually XPath expressions return a node list or a scalar depending on the expression, SimpleXML converts that to an array of SimpleXMLElement objects.

Comment: Hmmm. Is it possible to use xpath to find an `item` and then do an xpath on the result of that to find the custom attribute element? I perhaps simplified my XML in my question a bit too much.

Comment: Sure, see updated answer. You may also want to check out the http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp page on XPath syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I'm trying to do this now using a registered namespace: `xpath("//ns:item[@item-id='item34-test']/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id='taco']");` but it just isn't working. I think the namespace is causing problems. I may post another more specific question about it. Thanks again.